# How to send multiple media streams from one client using kurento client/utils API's?

Tags: kurento

I want to send 2 media streams to the webrtc peer. I am using kurento media server and kurento client API's. Kurento client APIs allows me to set options before creating webRTC peer connection. where we can specify local stream to be sent to the client.

It does not provide a way to send multiple streams from one client. I tried to add tracks from one stream to another and then send the stream. But when I do that media server crashes.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Multistream is not yet supported in the WebRtcEndpoint from Kurento.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying: I have been waiting for your reply :) Is there any other way i can achieve this. I have posted the secenario in kurento mailing list too. My goal is to have to 2 streams from one client to the different peers. say one stream from client1 to client2 and another from client1 to client3..

Comment: @piyush You need to have two separate connections in client1

Comment: @igracia are there any recent updates about this feature?

Comment: @igracia Is there any recent update about this feature about multistream?

Comment: @saurav not that I know of. You might want to reach out to the project mailing list.

Comment: @igracia Thank you for your response. Solved the problem by using two separate connections as suggested by you above as I was not sure if kms will be able to handle unified plan at the webRtcEnd Point level even if I make changes to the kurentoutils node module.